# Issue when I resize the browser window

Tags: css, resize

So this is our website http://www.greeceinsiders.com

if you resize the window you will see that the menu at the top-right gets out of the top-bar and it is ugly. How can I fix that? Can I play with the position of the  list?

Bonus: If anyone visits Greece he gets a free experience for helping us! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An easy fix is making the following changes in your CSS:

```
#top-bar > .menu {
    color: #FFFFFF;

    /* float: right; */ /*float: right removed */    
    height: 48px;
    margin-right: 40px;
    width: 490px;

    position: absolute; /* these are new additions */
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
}
```

Comment: No kidding, whenever you are in Greece drop us a line :)

Answer (score 0):

It's the pageTitle element that's causing it to get out of shape.

It seems like an empty element - can you just remove it?